# Сохранение результатов в БД C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо результаты выполнения программы записывать в базу данных. А точнее на фотографии определяется пол и возраст людей, как эти данные внести в базу, и какую именно субд лучше использовать ? Скриншот того, что необходимо занести в базу прикрепляю. Заранее спасибо, буду рад любым идеям и советом, в бд не силён.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
namespace FaceRecognizer.Face{
class RecognizerResponse
{
public string gender { get; set; }
public int genderProb { get; set; }
public int ageClass { get; set; }
public string ageDiapason { get; set; }
public int ageProb { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: У вас уже схема вашей базы данных есть?

Comment: Добрый вечер, нет схемы нет. Думаю буду использовать субд PostgreSQL там будет всего одна таблица, с полями ID, пол и возраст. Мне больше ничего не нужно. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как данные те что на фото, заполнять в таблицы. Я по началу думал их добавлять в DataGridView, но так же не особо знаю можно ли это сделать, и насколько это будет правильным.

Comment: @VladD могли бы Вы мне помочь ?

Comment: Ну давайте начнём сначала. Как выглядит информация, которую нужно поместить в базу данных, в коде? Вам же не картинку нужно поместить, да?

Comment: @VladD да мне нудно не картинку, а текст который вверху на примере. Результат распознавания поместить в бд. Вот участок кода отвечающей за вывод информации на форму.
RecognizerResponse faceInfo = facesInfo.personsData[i];
string toPrint = string.Format("Стать : {0}-{1:0}%\nВік : ({2})-{3:0}%",
(faceInfo.gender == "male" ? "Чоловік" : "Жінка"),
faceInfo.genderProb,
faceInfo.ageDiapason,
faceInfo.ageProb
 );
 graphycs.DrawString(toPrint, font, Brushes.Red, new PointF(faceRect.X, faceRect.Y - 40));
}

Comment: О, это уже лучше. Тогда добавьте в вопрос вашу структуру данных faceinfo.

Comment: @VladD скажите пожалуйста, могу ли я сюда вставить ссылку на github ? C моим проектом, могли бы вы глянуть, очень Вас прошу. Дело в том, что в проекте нету структуры, либо я настолько глуп, что не могу её найти...

Comment: Ну, добавить-то её можно, но нахождение структуры должно быть просто: в Visual Studio нажмите на имени типа F12.

Comment: @VladD человек помоги, в долгу не останусь) просто нужно эти данные на фото записать в таблицу, дальше сам справлюсь.

Comment: Не, с деньгами это не ко мне, я и так на работе. А как добавить данные в существующую таблицу — есть сотни способов. Например: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx

Comment: @VladD в примере, что вы отправили, данные заполняются вручную в таблицу насколько я понял, мне нужно что бы эти данные автоматически в таблицу заполнялись, после этапа распознавания. Ладно, чувствую я уже Вас достал. Прошу прощения, оставлю эту дурнаю затею с Базой Данных...

Comment: Ну да, вручную. Так иначе и никак, данные сами по себе в таблице не окажутся. В том и программирование состоит, что мы кодом делаем то, что выглядит как «автоматически». Прошло распознавание — запишите данные в базу, всё просто.